# Django ORM object id

Tags: django, django-orm, attributeerror

I suppose that the object IDs are auto created. Although, I encounter an Attribute error saying "'list' object has no attribute 'id'"

Below is my code module:

```
client = Client.objects.bulk_create([Client(name='WaltDisnep', created_at=timezone.now(),
                                                    updated_at=timezone.now()),
                                             Client(name='Google', created_at=timezone.now(),
                                                    updated_at=timezone.now()),
                                             Client(name='JetAirways', created_at=timezone.now(),
                                                    updated_at=timezone.now())])
building = Building.objects.create(description='TestBuilding',
                                           is_active=1, client_id=client.id,
                                country_code='NL')
```

Comment: `bulk_create` returns list not single id

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create `Building` objects for each of the `Client` objects then you can do this:

```
clients = Client.objects.bulk_create([
    Client(name='WaltDisney', created_at=timezone.now(), updated_at=timezone.now()),
    Client(name='Google', created_at=timezone.now(), updated_at=timezone.now()),
    Client(name='JetAirways', created_at=timezone.now(), updated_at=timezone.now())
])

# Now we have a list of clients we can iterate over.
buildings = []
for client in clients:
    # Let's make the description specific per client.
    description = '{} Building'.format(client.name)
    building = Building.objects.create(
        description=description,
        is_active=True,  # For truthiness use booleans not the set {0, 1}.
        client_id=client.id,
        country_code='NL'
    )
    buildings.append(building)
```

But be aware, if you aren't already doing so, it would be preferable to link these two models with a foreign key rather than manually recording the `client_id` on instances of `Building`, if that is in fact what you are doing here. I'd have to see your `models.py` file though to work out what you are actually up to in order to give you further advice about that.

Comment: I realised that Client is a foreign key on Building. So the problem, perhaps, lied in the queryset. There's no "id" field on the Client object (that's auto generated). Somehow,  client=client works.

Comment: Yes, `client=client` will work if it is the case you are using a foreign key. You can also do `client.building_set.add(Building.objects.create(**kwargs))` which is the same, just different syntax. See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add

Answer (score 0):

```
names = ['WaltDisney', 'Google', 'JetAirways']
now = timezone.now()
clients = Client.objects.bulk_create(
             [Client(name=name, created_at=now, updated_at=now) for name in names]
         )

buildings = [
    c.building_set.create(
        description='TestBuilding',
        is_active=1,
        country_code='NL',
    ) for c in clients
]
```